# How to use stateParam with auto complete in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written directive of auto-complete (Network Search)for user search. So when I select user, I am redirecting url with `$state` angular service.

```
var testurl = $state.href('home.generatemultipleinvoicewithfilters', {user_id: 1});
```

Here id of user is user_id, which comes from auto-complete. Now when page redirect, I want to above user_id should be selected. So Please tell me how to do this using auto-complete and stateParam.

Ref of auto-complete using Ajax call: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/ajax-based-autocomplete-typeahead-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: @NitsanBaleli Thanks for editing, Have you got my question. My question is how to get search, selected object when we reload page..

Comment: you will have to share more of your code and preferably create a plnkr so others can help more easily